# java.lang.Integer, Integer.compare does it only return the values of -1,0 and 1. If so

Tags: java

If so why does java documentation say a value less than `0` if `x < y`; and a value greater than `0` if `x > y`. Why can't they just say it returns `-1`,`0`,`1`?

Im pretty sure it only return values of `-1`,`0`,`1` and not sure if I want to do a comparison should I do
`if(Integer.compare(2,1) == 1)` or
`if(Integer.compare(2,1) > 0)`

Answer (score 2):

In case you check the implemenation, you will see:

```java
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

But in java doc of this method it says, that:

```
@return the value {@code 0} if {@code x == y};
        a value less than {@code 0} if {@code x < y}; and
        a value greater than {@code 0} if {@code x > y}
```

You definitely can check for `-1,0,1`, but I recommend you to check `<0,0,>0` - this is **much more reliable**. Just to protect the code.

```java
if(Integer.compare(2,1) == 1) {} // this is 100% correct
if(Integer.compare(2,1) > 0)  {} // this is 999% correct
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"java.lang.Integer, Integer.compare does it only return the values of -1,0 and 1. ..."*

Yes, it does.  Here is the code from the *OpenJDK*.

*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L1486)*.

```java
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

> *"If so why does java documentation say a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y. Why can't they just say it returns -1, 0, 1? ..."*

Because technically those conditional statements would suffice.

> *"... Im pretty sure it only return values of -1,0, 1 and not sure if I want to do a comparison should I do if(Integer.compare(2,1) == 1) or if(Integer.compare(2,1) > 0)"*

Either will work; there wouldn't be any performance impact here.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation could change as long as it complies with the [documented behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)). Return values of -1, 0, 1 are values consistent with that. Although it is unlikely to change the future safe way of comparing would be to compare with less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero.